# Media queries just won't work when I host the files to my site

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've been trying to upload a fictious site I made into a course onto my site. I have uploaded it at the following place : https://codehero.life/projects/omnifood/index.html

The problem is that the media queries work just fine when I am trying the site on localhost. Everything just works fine on a localhost. However on the site, queries just don't work. I've implemented a hamburger menu when its a mobile, but nothing such happens, I get empty spaces, etc. You can check by going on the above link.

I've implemented the 'viewport' tag, removed the comments from my code, still doesn't work. Even tried to put the entire media query file into my styles.css rather than separate CSS, but still doesn't work. I have tried having the 'media only' and 'media' as well, doesn't work. Where am i going wrong?

Here is the queries.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .hero-text-box{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 2%;
    }

    .row{padding: 0 2%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px){
    body{font-size: 18px;}

    section{padding: 60px 0;}

    .long-copy{
        width: 78%;
        margin-left: 11%;
    }

    .steps-box{margin-top: 10px;}
    
    .steps-box:last-child{margin-top: 10px;}
    
    .work-steps{margin-bottom: 40px;}
    
    .work-steps:last-of-type{margin-bottom: 60px;}

    .app-screen{width: 50%;}

    .icon-small{
        width: 17px;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .city-feature{font-size: 90%;}

    .plan-box{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .plan-price{font-size: 250%;}

    .contact-form{width: 80%;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){

    body{font-size: 16px;}
    section{padding: 30px 0;}
    .row,.hero-text-box{padding: 0 4%;}

    .col{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0 4% 0;
    }

    .main-nav{display: none;}
    .mobile-nav-icon{display: inline-block;}

    .main-nav{
        float: left;
        margin-top: 25px;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }

    .main-nav li{
        display: block;
    }

    .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited{
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .sticky .main-nav li a:link,
    .sticky .main-nav li a:visited{
        padding: 10px 0;
    }

    .sticky .main-nav{ margin-top: 10px;}

    .sticky .mobile-nav-icon i{color: black;}
    .sticky .mobile-nav-icon {margin-top: 10px;}

    .long-copy{
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    h1{font-size: 180%;}
    h1{font-size: 150%;}

    .work-steps{margin-bottom: 20px;}
    
    .work-steps:last-of-type{margin-bottom: 20px;}

    .work-steps div{
        
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        padding: 4px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        font-size: 120%
    }

    .center-box{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .section-features{
        text-align: center;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
    section{padding: 25px 0;}
    .contact-form{width: 100%;}

}
```

Head of the html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/queries.css">
```

Comment: Just looked at the site, looks like everything is working. I resized your site to 1100 and I see the css for `.hero-text-box` kicking in. The hamburger icon also appears on mobile

Comment: The above link worked fine for me using dev console in chrome. Hamburger menu worked. 3 lines or X.

Comment: I just checked the site using another phone and yes it works! I am using Edge Dev in my PC so maybe that might be doing something. Thank you very much for verifying!

Answer (score 0):

Because css is read from top to bottom. The rule that is set last, is the one that will be executed.
Please ensure you put all your media queries at the bottom os your css files.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { //If my screen fits this size
   .your-class {
       color: black; //Paint it black
    }
}

.your-class {
    color: blue; //Now, forget about everything and paint it blue!
}
```

Comment: Found my answer, everything was working properly, it was a fault at my end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work just fine when I checked it using an actual phone. I am using Edge Dev on the PC so maybe it may be showing me a cached copy of the site or maybe dev tools not working properly. Was able to verify because of the comments.

Comment: The lesson here is to always check your work on multiple browsers